# Git remove changes

Tags: git, github

I have team project and I have done some changes on code but not committed yet. I want to bring latest version of code from github which doesnt have the changes I have done but not committed. I do not remember which classes I changed. I just need to remove most recent changes after last commit.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all your non-commited changes:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

As pointed out by sleske, this will **completely remove** all your changes! If you just want to be able to `git pull` from GitHub, you could `stash` your changes to temporarily remove them, `pull` and then use `stash pop` to bring back your changes:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Comment: Warning: This will *irretrievably* remove your changes. You will not be able to get them back later! If that is what you want, OK. Otherweise there are ways to remove the changes, but keep them for later use (git stash, temporary commit).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a code editor like atom you might have a git tab where you can go back to the latest pull that should look like this :[image]

By using this option you will be able to always go back and see the diferences.
If not you should you `git stash` then `git pull` and you will be back to the last version on the repo.
You can always go back by using this method aswell by using the git command : `git stash pop`
Good Luck coding!